# How to tell what color your car is (not in door jamb)

Tags: paint

I bought my car used, it is a 2006 Scion tC. The original color of the car is silver, as I gleaned from looking at my door jamb. However, I believe the previous owner painted the top half of the car (the hood, half of the mirrors, and from the windows up) a metallic blue color. I would like to repaint a section of the car the blue color, but I'm not sure how I could identify what specific blue it is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take it to a car body shop and have them color match it ... about your only choice.

Comment: There are usually multiple places where the VIN and color code should be located. But if for some strange reason all of the plates are gone then taking a small part (like the fuel filler door) to the paint store/body shop is enough.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I think you may have misread; the user wants to know what the non-original paint is.

Comment: Ah, my bad. In that case taking a body part to the shop is the only way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to color match automotive paint properly. Professionals (at a body shop, for instance) would be able to do it, as suggested by Paulster2.

A specialty automotive paint retailer (not a general auto parts store) will be able to match colors, but it is often a bit of a trial-and-error process. If you are able to remove your mirror and bring it into the store, they might have a color matching machine that they can put it in.

Answer (score 1):

Take your make and model to a body shop supplier, they will be able to match the OEM color on their computer or book.